# make 1 page no scroll CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

want to show 1 static page contain everything without a scroll

tried to make boddy padding 0 and overflow: hidden but nothing work
also tried the below page-header and background-image code also not work

````
    display: flex!important;
    flex-direction: column!important;
    min-height: 1vh!important;
}```

```.background-image {flex-grow: 1!important;}

1 page with cover image and footer info, dont know what i am missing to fix that
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the body to have an overflow-y of hidden in css it will not allow the user to scroll down the page.

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go for the root html element, you can style it to:

```
html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

The browser will interpret this as the html would use 100% of the usable device width space and hide the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to avoid scrolling but instead make the page elements fit on the screen so there is no scrollbar and still everything is visible.

As a start, you could make the .main class (which only contains your footer) absolutely positioned at the bottom and take it from there

```
.main {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

or, what I'd prefer, set the wrapper to be a flexbox:
UPDATED

```
body.home {
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

body.home .wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

/* Not needed anymore */
body.home .carousel {
}
body.home .main {
}
```

Comment: Hello Man thank you so much for taking time to answer and help me,
i have tried the first soultion and works sooo good on main page, but makes the other page top dissapear, you can see the about.

2nd soultion work so good but it doesnt fit everything and the screen has 2 much white under the footer, iam applying the 2nd option now

big thanks again

Comment: No problem. I've added to my answer a fix so you can apply the styles just to the front page.

Comment: Man it was a mistake to have that getin touch, i just removed it, 
shall io try this fix anyway.
i dont want that getin touch.
only this classic footer i have is great

Comment: I had a look onto your page again and updated my answer. If you replace the old code with the one after UPDATED, you should not see any white space under the footer anymore.

Comment: Hi man, i used that home code like this and it works amazing,

body.home .main {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}

talking about the footer, do you know how can i make that line at the full width so i can seprate them like 2 parts?
i tried alot, but it seems little bit tricky or my brain is closed at that point :)

Comment: Try adding
footer .container { width: 100%;}
and
footer .textwidget { width: 100%; justify-content: center; }
And please consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: hello again, and thank you so much for replying, 
it doesn't fix the line to be full :( 

also i have last 2 issue, i made the ,main nav menu from transp to white, do you think my soulotion is good. 

and last thing for the footer after contact us, i have used the following css to make them 1 line horizantal:

.col-md-4 {width:100%;
float:right;}

.textwidget{display:flex;
 float:left;
}
the only problem i am facing now is that the contact us text get wrap when the screen is small like mobile for example, i tried with the word-break they using but it doesnt word, do you know why ?

Comment: Well, instead of avoiding text-wrap, you should avoid having all items in one line for mobile, like this (the 800px value is a guess, change that until it fits your needs): @media screen and (max-width: 800px) { footer .textwidget {display: block; text-align: center;} }

Comment: hi man, the first soulotion about 1 static page, didnt work on mobile, i dont care for the mobile to be 1 page, but with this soulotion th efooter goes up on mobile
see the screen shot please: https://ibb.co/Brm2v3C

Comment: i used the same soulotion for the footer and made the following for the mobile view :) @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {body.home .main {
position:  relative;
 }}

i thjink its ok and wont make any issue, what you think ? 

big thanks again :)

Comment: Jep, that looks ok now. Congrats. Probably just change the 800px to 1000px as in between those values the text still wraps, you can check by resizing your browser window. Just play around with it a bit.

Comment: the 1000 works great, 
but still somethimes while i am changing the size, the footer jumps up?
also did you figure out how to make that under line full at the footer and looks like a split ?

big thanks really man you are so nice and you helped me dozen :)